# Symfony : "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP" while trying to use createView()

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm a beginner on Symfony and I'm trying to render a form from my controller by following the tutorial available through the following link : https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-forms

Note : I'm using the annotations package to declare my routes.

I created the following php files in hope to create my form :

**src/Entity/Task.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $task;
    protected $dueDate;

    public function getTask(): string
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    public function setTask(string $task): void
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function getDueDate(): ?\DateTime
    {
        return $this->dueDate;
    }

    public function setDueDate(?\DateTime $dueDate): void
    {
        $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    }
}
```

**src/Form/Type/TaskType.php**

```
<?php
// src/Form/Type/TaskType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('task', TextType::class)
            ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Task::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**src/Controller/MainController.php**

```
<?php
// src/Controller/MainController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Form\Type\TaskType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    *   @Route("/main/")
    */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        // creates a task object and initializes some data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

        return $this->render("main.html.twig", [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I also created the following twig template for my controller :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome, mortal !</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome, mortal !</h1>
        <div>
            {{ form(form) }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is, whenever I try to log to my page, I end up with a RuntimeException error with the following message :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP." at D:\Development\Capture\apache\htdocs\Tutorial\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php line 148
Hide context    Show trace
[▼
  "exception" => RuntimeException {#166 ▼
    #message: "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP."
    #code: 0
    #file: "D:\Development\Capture\apache\htdocs\Tutorial\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php"
    #line: 148
    trace: {▶}
  }
]
```

The callstack seem to always point the createView() function in the MainController.php file. I also tried to use the renderForm function instead of the render function (with the appropriate changes to the $form call), but I get the same error while doing so.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong ?

---

**EDIT :** as asked by WillB, here's my framework session configuration file :

```
# see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

I also tried to change session.auto_start value in php.ini from 1 to 0, but it triggered one warning and three separate errors instead.

- Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/tmp\sess_5f7b45aba4b47fea3d36e03aaebc139c, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
- (CRITICAL) Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/tmp\sess_5f7b45aba4b47fea3d36e03aaebc139c, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)" at D:\Development\Capture\apache\htdocs\Tutorial\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler.php line 49
  {
  "exception": {}
  }
- (CRITICAL) Exception thrown when handling an exception (ErrorException: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/tmp\sess_5f7b45aba4b47fea3d36e03aaebc139c, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) at D:\Development\Capture\apache\htdocs\Tutorial\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler.php line 49)
  {
  "exception": {}
  }
- (CRITICAL) Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/tmp\sess_5f7b45aba4b47fea3d36e03aaebc139c, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)" at D:\Development\Capture\apache\htdocs\Tutorial\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler.php line 49
  {
  "exception": {}
  }

Comment: Check your `phpinfo()` and ensure [`session.auto_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) is `0`. Otherwise check your project code for `session_start()`. Usually found in your `App\Kernel` or `index.php` files, as they initialize Symfony for your web application.

Comment: @WillB. I tried your solution, but now I am stuck with three errors. All of them refer to "open(/tmp\sess_27ba4c6384da9bda43e82eeff4b04055, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)", at \vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\Handler\StrictSessionHandler.php line 49

Comment: @Eox Please update your question and provide your [framework session](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) configuration.

Comment: @Eox also please clarify what specifically did you change? eg: Was `session.auto_start` changed? Or did you find `session_start()` some place in your project files? For clarification, I asked to check, not change.

Comment: @WillB. I updated the main post with the information you requested. Tell me if I missed something.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message you are facing? Please add it to your question by editing it

Comment: The error message indicates that you misconfigured the session directory. `/tmp` does not exist on Windows

Comment: @NicoHaase Indeed, it looks like my session.save_path variable was incomplete in php.ini. 

I changed the content of this variable to where these session files were supposed to be (in my case, C:/tmp), and managed to finally make my webpage work. I however need to keep the value of session.auto_start to 0 : switching this configuration variable back to 1 still triggers the "already started by PHP" error.

This is still a massive improvement, so thanks a lot NicoHaase and WillB. Is there is a way to fix the session error however or should I keep my session.auto_start variable to 0 ?

Comment: In Symfony I recommend using the  [`framework.session` config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#configuration) with `handler_id: 'session.handler.native_file'` and `save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'` as displayed in the docs.  Additionally in standard PHP it is also not recommended to auto start the sessions, instead in non-Symfony apps you should call `if (!session_id()) { session_start(); }` manually. Symfony uses lazy session management and starts the session once it is needed automatically, making the auto_start php.ini setting incompatible.

Comment: The main questions would be, is auto_start needed for another non-Symfony application? If so you would need to disable auto_start for your Symfony envirnoment possibly with a `.user.ini` file or Web Server override, depending on if you are using Apache, Nginix and/or PHP-FPM . And are you integrating your Symfony app into another legacy application?